# jquery - dynamic menu - click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a horizontal category bar. this is populated by php - i set a data-cat-id property on the anchor. then use a jquery click function to get this value like this:

```
        $('.filterCat').click(function() {
            alert('cat id is:'+$(this).data("cat-id"))
            return false;
        });
```

This works fine. But the horizontal bar has a function that adds list elements to a "more" sub menu when the width gets smaller than its content. using the code:

$(function() {
    alignMenu();

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $("#horizontal").append($("#horizontal li.hideshow ul").html());
  $("#horizontal li.hideshow").remove();
  alignMenu();
});

function alignMenu() {
  var w = 0;
  var mw = $("#horizontal").width() - 150;
  var i = -1;
  var menuhtml = '';
  jQuery.each($("#horizontal").children(), function() {
    i++;
    w += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    if (mw < w) {
      menuhtml += $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
  $("#horizontal").append(
    '<li  style="position:relative;" href="#" class="hideshow">' + '<a href="#">More ' + '<span style="font-size:13px">&#8595;</span>' + '</a><ul>' + menuhtml + '</ul></li>');
  $("#horizontal li.hideshow ul").css("top",
    $("#horizontal li.hideshow").outerHeight(true) + "px");
  $("#horizontal li.hideshow").click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").toggle();
  });
  if (menuhtml == '') {
    $("#horizontal li.hideshow").hide();
  } else {
    $("#horizontal li.hideshow").show();
  }
}
```

});

This also works but now when there is a "more" button (because the content is bigger) the click function does not work anymore.

i have made a fiddle - if you click on a normal menu item it shows the alert, but if you click on a item that is places under "more" it does nothing see FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/quosa60e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements `.click()` does not work

```
document.on('click','SELECTOR',function(){});
```

So you should use:

```
$(document).on('click','.filterCat',function() {
    alert('cat id is:'+$(this).data("cat-id"))
    return false;
});
```